# How to fetch a specific email address from json array in azure logic app

Tags: regex, azure-logic-apps

I have a requirement where I want to fetch an email address from specific domain which is stored in json array variable in Azure logic app.

For example my jsonarray contain below elements.

jsonarray = ["abc@gmail.com","xyz@yahoo.com","wry@gmail.com"]

Now, from the above array how to fetch values for only @gmail.com domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Filter array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#filter-array-action) action:

[image]

The result seems to be no problem：

[image]